# Is it possible to add a class to an input in observablehq?

Tags: observablehq

I would like to add a custom class to an `observablehq` input so that Bootstrap styling can be applied (e.g. `Inputs.select`). Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Here is an example:

```
viewof bins = {
  const input = Inputs.range([3, 20], { step: 1, label: "Bins" });
  input.classList.add("hello");
  return input;
}
```

https://observablehq.com/d/54079bd6ddbb4e71